# AWS Lambda call url which takes longer than Lambda execution limit

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

**Context**

I want to run an AWS Lambda, call an endpoint (fire and forget) then stop the Lambda - all the while the endpoint is whirling away happily on it's own.

---

**Attempts**

*1.*

Using a timeout, e.g.

```
try:
    requests.get(url, timeout=0.001)

except requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout:
    ...
```

*2.*

Using an async call with grequest:

```
import grequests
...

def handler(event, context):

    try:
        ...

        req = grequests.get(url)
        grequests.send(req, grequests.Pool(1))

        return {
            'statusCode': 200,
            'body': "Lambda done"
        }

    except Exception:
        logger.exception('Error while running lambda')
        raise
```

These requests don't appear to reach the API, it's almost like the request is being cancelled.

Any ideas why?

---

**Question**

How can a Lambda call a URL which takes a long time to complete? Thanks.

Comment: How long is *long time*? AWS will kill your lambda function after 300 seconds. See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/limits.html

Comment: More than the lambda execution time limit of 300s

Comment: the url you are trying to hit from lambda, is it a public endpoint? Is you lambda inside the vpc? if so it should be launched inside a public subnet, check your n/w configuration.

Comment: @VaisakhPS a lambda function in a public subnet will not have Internet access, since lambda functions don't get public IP addresses assigned to them regardless of subnet they are in. If the Lambda is in a VPC, then it must be in a private subnet with a NAT gatetway in order to have Internet access.

Comment: @greenlamponatable Are you sure your function has network access to connect to the API endpoint? Is the API endpoint public or inside your VPC? Are you deploying the Lambda function inside a VPC?

Comment: @MarkB you are right, a NAT gateway is required with private subnet. also if you want internet access you can also attach an `Elastic IP` to the `ENI` of the Lambda function.

Comment: @VaisakhPS no you can't attach an Elastic IP to the ENI of the Lambda function because the ENI is constantly being created and deleted automatically by the Lambda service when invocations come in.

Comment: yeah, the lambda can reach the endpoint

Answer (score 1):

To anyone reading this: I fixed my problem by using AWS Batch.

Answer (score 0):

You have to increase the timeout on your function. Depending on how you have defined your function, you can increase the default timeout of 300 seconds on the function page or inside your cloudformation script.

The timeout defined inside your function has no effect on lambda functionality. AWS Lambda will kill your function after 300 seconds regardless of any timeout defined inside your script. See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/limits.html